# Flink Avro Error Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo

Tags: java, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to convert a HashMap<String, Object> to an Avro record. I get this runtime exception when I do a
`DataStream<AvroRecord> dsRpvSchema = filteredVlfRPV.flatMap(new MessageFlattener()) .name("ToAvroSchema").uid("ToAvroSchema").startNewChain();`

Not sure what the issue is with Flink converting the valid avro record to Flink Avro.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroTypeInfo.generateFieldsFromAvroSchema(AvroTypeInfo.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroTypeInfo.<init>(AvroTypeInfo.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.utils.AvroKryoSerializerUtils.createAvroTypeInfo(AvroKryoSerializerUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1653)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1559)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoWithTypeHierarchy(TypeExtractor.java:866)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateCreateTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:747)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(TypeExtractor.java:531)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getFlatMapReturnTypes(TypeExtractor.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.flatMap(DataStream.java:637)
```

I do see two questions on this but no answers provided:

1. [Flink Kafka : Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826065/flink-kafka-expecting-type-to-be-a-pojotypeinfo)
2. [Deserialize Avro from kafka as SpecificRecord Failing. Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399873/deserialize-avro-from-kafka-as-specificrecord-failing-expecting-type-to-be-a-po)

UPDATE: 02/01/2022. Below is the `AvroRecord` class definition.

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageEncoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.message.SchemaStore;

@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class AvroRecord extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9071485731787422200L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"AvroRecord\",\"namespace\":\"com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_id\",\"type\":\"string\",\"doc\":\"car_id\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

  private static SpecificData MODEL$ = new SpecificData();

  private static final BinaryMessageEncoder<AvroRecord> ENCODER =
      new BinaryMessageEncoder<AvroRecord>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<AvroRecord> DECODER =
      new BinaryMessageDecoder<AvroRecord>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageEncoder instance used by this class.
   * @return the message encoder used by this class
   */
  public static BinaryMessageEncoder<AvroRecord> getEncoder() {
    return ENCODER;
  }

  /**
   * Return the BinaryMessageDecoder instance used by this class.
   * @return the message decoder used by this class
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<AvroRecord> getDecoder() {
    return DECODER;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class that uses the specified {@link SchemaStore}.
   * @param resolver a {@link SchemaStore} used to find schemas by fingerprint
   * @return a BinaryMessageDecoder instance for this class backed by the given SchemaStore
   */
  public static BinaryMessageDecoder<AvroRecord> createDecoder(SchemaStore resolver) {
    return new BinaryMessageDecoder<AvroRecord>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$, resolver);
  }

  /**
   * Serializes this AvroRecord to a ByteBuffer.
   * @return a buffer holding the serialized data for this instance
   * @throws java.io.IOException if this instance could not be serialized
   */
  public java.nio.ByteBuffer toByteBuffer() throws java.io.IOException {
    return ENCODER.encode(this);
  }

  /**
   * Deserializes a AvroRecord from a ByteBuffer.
   * @param b a byte buffer holding serialized data for an instance of this class
   * @return a AvroRecord instance decoded from the given buffer
   * @throws java.io.IOException if the given bytes could not be deserialized into an instance of this class
   */
  public static AvroRecord fromByteBuffer(
      java.nio.ByteBuffer b) throws java.io.IOException {
    return DECODER.decode(b);
  }

  /** car_id */
   private java.lang.CharSequence _id;

  /**
   * Default constructor.  Note that this does not initialize fields
   * to their default values from the schema.  If that is desired then
   * one should use <code>newBuilder()</code>.
   */
  public AvroRecord() {}

  /**
   * All-args constructor.
   * @param _id car_id
   */
  public AvroRecord(java.lang.CharSequence _id) {
    this._id = _id;
  }

  public org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData getSpecificData() { return MODEL$; }
  public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  // Used by DatumWriter.  Applications should not call.
  public java.lang.Object get(int field$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: return _id;
    default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + field$);
    }
  }

  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call.
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: _id = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    default: throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + field$);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the '_id' field.
   * @return car_id
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getId$1() {
    return _id;
  }


  /**
   * Sets the value of the '_id' field.
   * car_id
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setId$1(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new AvroRecord RecordBuilder.
   * @return A new AvroRecord RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder();
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new AvroRecord RecordBuilder by copying an existing Builder.
   * @param other The existing builder to copy.
   * @return A new AvroRecord RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder newBuilder(com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder other) {
    if (other == null) {
      return new com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder();
    } else {
      return new com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder(other);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new AvroRecord RecordBuilder by copying an existing AvroRecord instance.
   * @param other The existing instance to copy.
   * @return A new AvroRecord RecordBuilder
   */
  public static com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder newBuilder(com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord other) {
    if (other == null) {
      return new com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder();
    } else {
      return new com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder(other);
    }
  }

  /**
   * RecordBuilder for AvroRecord instances.
   */
  @org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
  public static class Builder extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase<AvroRecord>
    implements org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder<AvroRecord> {

    /** car_id */
    private java.lang.CharSequence _id;

    /** Creates a new Builder */
    private Builder() {
      super(SCHEMA$);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing Builder.
     * @param other The existing Builder to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder other) {
      super(other);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other._id)) {
        this._id = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other._id);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = other.fieldSetFlags()[0];
      }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Builder by copying an existing AvroRecord instance
     * @param other The existing instance to copy.
     */
    private Builder(com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord other) {
      super(SCHEMA$);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other._id)) {
        this._id = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other._id);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
    }

    /**
      * Gets the value of the '_id' field.
      * car_id
      * @return The value.
      */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getId$1() {
      return _id;
    }


    /**
      * Sets the value of the '_id' field.
      * car_id
      * @param value The value of '_id'.
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder setId$1(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[0], value);
      this._id = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      return this;
    }

    /**
      * Checks whether the '_id' field has been set.
      * car_id
      * @return True if the '_id' field has been set, false otherwise.
      */
    public boolean hasId$1() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[0];
    }


    /**
      * Clears the value of the '_id' field.
      * car_id
      * @return This builder.
      */
    public com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro.AvroRecord.Builder clearId$1() {
      _id = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = false;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AvroRecord build() {
      try {
        AvroRecord record = new AvroRecord();
        record._id = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this._id : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
        return record;
      } catch (org.apache.avro.AvroMissingFieldException e) {
        throw e;
      } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<AvroRecord>
    WRITER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter<AvroRecord>)MODEL$.createDatumWriter(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void writeExternal(java.io.ObjectOutput out)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    WRITER$.write(this, SpecificData.getEncoder(out));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static final org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<AvroRecord>
    READER$ = (org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader<AvroRecord>)MODEL$.createDatumReader(SCHEMA$);

  @Override public void readExternal(java.io.ObjectInput in)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    READER$.read(this, SpecificData.getDecoder(in));
  }

  @Override protected boolean hasCustomCoders() { return true; }

  @Override public void customEncode(org.apache.avro.io.Encoder out)
    throws java.io.IOException
  {
    out.writeString(this._id);

  }

  @Override public void customDecode(org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder in)
    throws java.io.IOException
  {
    org.apache.avro.Schema.Field[] fieldOrder = in.readFieldOrderIfDiff();
    if (fieldOrder == null) {
      this._id = in.readString(this._id instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this._id : null);

    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        switch (fieldOrder[i].pos()) {
        case 0:
          this._id = in.readString(this._id instanceof Utf8 ? (Utf8)this._id : null);
          break;

        default:
          throw new java.io.IOException("Corrupt ResolvingDecoder.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The AVRO schema (.avsc) file looks like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "com.sample.dataplatform.stream.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "AvroRecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "_id",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "car_id"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you share what the AvroRecord class looks like?

Comment: Its an auto generated Java class. Updated my question with the same.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-generated class didn't meet the flink POJO requirements. You could try set the field visibility to public by updating the POM. [Flink POJO requirments](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/serialization/types_serialization/#pojos) e.g

```
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                <fieldVisibility>PUBLIC</fieldVisibility>
                <createSetters>true</createSetters>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```